# Even mark L.control.layers - leaflet

Tags: events, leaflet, controls, layer, leaflet.markercluster

I have a Leaflet.Control.Layers, where I add the layers of my map. Which event I use to know which layers are checked or not.

Comment: You can test if a layer is added to a map with `map.hasLayer(layer)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need an event, you can use

```
layer.on('add', function(e) {
    ...
});

layer.on('remove', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

And you can check if a layer is currently added to the map with

```
if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
...
}
```